# best jquery rounded corners, working on divs & tables?

Tags: jquery

I must have tried about 5 different plugins, each having downsides. Firstly I need it to work on a div with a specified height, and still round the corners if there is no content. Secondly it needs to work on tables (havent found any that "work")

I dont really want to use images, as this means 4images for the main content div then 4images for the table, jquery would be much easier

Any advice? Thanks

Below is the code I have tried with cury corners

```
 $(document).ready( function()
{

  $('.content').corner();
  $('nav_links').corner();


});
</script>

 <div id="content" class="content">      

      <table id="nav_links" class="nav_links" cellpadding="7">
        <tr>
        <td class="nav_background"><a href="index.html">Home</a></td>
        <td class="nav_background"><a href="#">1</a></td>
        <td class="nav_background"><a href="#">2</a></td>
        <td class="nav_background"><a href="#">3</a></td>
        <td class="nav_background"><a href="#">4</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You should not be using a `table` in the first place...

Comment: A table is meant for tabular data (i.e. spreadsheet like data). Using it to display navigation links is considered poor markup. Using a `ul/li` list has been a more accepted way of building navigation for a number of years now.

Comment: Yeah, if you must use tables, then use images to make your corners. Otherwise use the corners plugin (see John's answer) or check out this plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jquerycurvycorners/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is obsolete, and the [tag:corners] tag is [undergoing burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295233/should-the-corners-tag-be-burninated-removed-from-all-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the [Corners plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/corners), which works without images. Your code is almost correct, however you seem to have mixed your jQuery selectors up. To select an element with id `myId`, use `$('#myId')`, see also selectors in the [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

Working code for FireFox:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.corners.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function()
{
  $('#nav_links').corners('20px');
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #nav_links { background-color: #c0c0c0; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content" class="content">      
          <table id="nav_links" class="nav_links" cellpadding="7">
                <tr>
                <td class="nav_background"><a href="index.html">Home</a></td>
                <td class="nav_background"><a href="#">1</a></td>
                <td class="nav_background"><a href="#">2</a></td>
                <td class="nav_background"><a href="#">3</a></td>
                <td class="nav_background"><a href="#">4</a></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that this requires you've downloaded and installed the plugin. As you write in the comments, this doesn't seem to work for tables in IE. The best solution in this cases would be to transform the table to a list as suggested by dcneiner, since this *is* semantically a *list of pages/links* anyway.
If you want to stick to the table, and are able to specify an explicit width, use a background div to do what you want:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.corners.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function()
{
  $('#nav_links_background').corners('20px');
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #nav_links_background { background-color: #c0c0c0; width: 20em;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">      
    <div id="nav_links_background">
         <table id="nav_links" cellpadding="7">
                <tr>
                <td class="nav_background"><a href="index.html">Home</a></td>
                <td class="nav_background"><a href="#">1</a></td>
                <td class="nav_background"><a href="#">2</a></td>
                <td class="nav_background"><a href="#">3</a></td>
                <td class="nav_background"><a href="#">4</a></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just one problem...only the top part corners in IE =( problem I have always had, really annoying.

Comment: Also the table doesnt corner at all in IE